# Ignore based kustomization in the overlay kustomization

Tags: kubernetes

Currently I have a kubernetes config directory as following:

```
├── base
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
|   ├── main-ingress.yaml
│   └── sub-ingress.yaml
└── overlays
    ├── dev-1
    │   ├── kustomization.yaml
    │   ├── main-ingress.yaml
    │   └── sub-ingress.yaml
    ├── dev-2
    │   ├── kustomization.yaml
    │   ├── main-ingress.yaml
    │   └── sub-ingress.yaml
    └── prod
        ├── main-ingress.yaml
        └── kustomization.yaml
```

In the `/base/kustomization.yaml` :

```
apiVersion: [...]
kind: Kustomization

configMapGenerator:
[...]

resources:
 - main-ingress.yaml
 - sub-ingress.yaml
```

In the `/overlays/prod/kustomization.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: [...]
kind: Kustomization

patchesStrategicMerge:
 - main-ingress.yaml

resources:
 - ../../base
```

In the `/overlays/dev-1/kustomization.yaml` and `/overlays/dev-2/kustomization.yaml` :

```
apiVersion: [...]
kind: Kustomization

patchesStrategicMerge:
 - main-ingress.yaml
 - sub-ingress.yaml

resources:
 - ../../base
```

In the `/base/sub-ingress.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: [...]
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sub-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: [...]
    nginx.org/server-snippets: |
        ...nginx-rules...
spec:
```

In the `/overlays/dev-1/sub-ingress.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: [...]
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sub-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myname.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 9999
        path: /my-app
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myname.com
    secretName: my-tls
```

In the `/overlays/dev-2/sub-ingress.yaml`

```
apiVersion: [...]
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sub-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myname2.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 9999
        path: /my-app
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myname2.com
    secretName: my-tls
```

Now when I run the build command `kustomize build --enable_alpha_plugins prod/`, the errors will be shown:

```
nil value at `spec.tls.secretName` ignored in mutation attempt
nil value at `spec.rules.http.paths.backend.serviceName` ignored in mutation attempt
nil value at `spec.backend.serviceName` ignored in mutation attempt
```

It seems that the kustomize plugin is getting the issue when trying to build a result of `sub-ingress.yaml` based on based config but there is no corresponding config file in the overlay `prod`.

Comment: Your directory tree looks ok. Could you please send the yaml files for `base` and `dev` so that the problem can be reproduced locally? In addition, I do not think that `--enable_alpha_plugins` is required in your use-case.

Comment: Hi @FabriceJammes I already updated the content of `sub-ingress.yaml` file. For the `--enable_alpha_plugins` maybe not necessary for my case. I just describe what I already did in the question.

Comment: Could you please explain why `apiVersion` is under brackets? I'd like to reproduce the problem on my workstation but I'd appreciate not to edit at all your yaml files.